# How to use a customized formula on a series in pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file which day wise data from 2016-2023 and a revenue column. I use a pivot to analyse the year wise revenue. I want to add another column which can do a running total year wise ( as I have created a pivot that way ) and then calculate the average of it ( for each year ) and write it in the pivot table itself. I know the calculated field feature in pivot table but my requirement is not based on one formula. It will first calculate the running total and then average.

[image]

Yellow column here is the input data that I have. Pivot table along with Running total average is the output that I desire.

Comment: What specific problem did you run into with your attempt?

Comment: Why not just add a running total column to your source data? Side note, the average of a running total does not seem like a meaningful metric.

Comment: Adding running total wont make sense as I want this average of running total to be changed when I change the pivot. So on designing the pivot table, the excel should filter down the data, then calculate the running total average and give it next to the pivot table

Comment: If you added the running total to the source data, then yes the average would change as you changed the pivot.

Comment: Add your source table to the data model, after which you can create a measure within Power Pivot to achieve your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a way or insert a custom formula, but for work, I write the formula in the PivotTable Data range and insert it as a field to the pivot table. If the formulas recalculate for any reason outside of the table then you can just right click on the pivot table and click "Refresh" and it will adjust the pivot table accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).